# From a shell script, how can I check whether a table in db2 database exists or not?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, db2

I am trying to write a script which allows to check if the db2 table exists or not. If it exists I will continue to touch a file if not exists then it has to wait for 30 min and try to check the same after 30 min. How might I achieve this?

```
#!/bin/sh
db2 "connect to <database> user <username> using <password>"
Variable=`db2 -x "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SCHEMA.TABLEA WHERE 1=2"`

while read Variable ;
do
  if $Variable=0 
  then touch triggerfile.txt
  else 
  sleep 30
 fi
  done
```

Comment: What is your code so far? Any errors?

Comment: Updated my code

Answer (score 1):

You want to continually poll (without limitation on time) for a table to exist? Might be more readable to use bash or korn syntax, and avoid backticks but that's your choice.

Usual caveats apply, don't hardcode the password.

Apart from the looping logic, you might try this inside the loop (bash or ksh syntax shown below), initialising the variables to suit yourself:

```
db2 "connect to $dbname user $username using $passwd"
(( $? > 0 )) && print "Failed to connect to database " && exit 1
db2 -o- "select 1 from syscat.tables where tabschema=$schema and tabname=$tabname with ur"
rc=$?
# rc = 0 : the table exists in that schema
# rc= 1  : the table does not exist
(( rc == 1 )) && touch triggerfile.txt
# rc >= 2 : some warning or error, need to investigate and correct
(( rc >= 2)) && print "problems querying syscat.tables" && exit 1
db2 -o- connect reset
```

Comment: Thanks!! What if I need to put it in the loop as it has to go for 5 loops to check the table existance , after that we can send an email.

Comment: Use a 'for' loop or a 'while' loop around the above-example block.

Comment: I have tried by appending that , but am not successful ! (Am very much new to unix)